# Cycle animation or active class through Vue js loop

Tags: loops, vuejs2, vue-component, settimeout, v-for

I have already created this effect in an old vanilla js app. I have a series of blocks that have a hover animation, and when there is no hover, the animation cycles block by block in succession.

I have rebuilt the whole app in Vue js, and everything else has been much easier. This is the only part of the app that I am struggling to do the "Vue" way with no dom manipulation. Basically I have a 3 second timeout where the component gets the "active" class, and then the class switches to the next component in the v-for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to represent the relevant state using properties in `data`. Whenever you feel tempted to manipulate the DOM directly just update some state instead and wire that up to the template accordingly.

Hopefully this demo does what you want:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      active: 0,
      
      items: [
        'Red',
        'Green',
        'Blue',
        'Yellow'
      ]
    }
  },
  
  mounted () {
    this.startTimer()
  },
  
  destroyed () {
    this.stopTimer()
  },
  
  methods: {
    onMouseEnter (index) {
      this.stopTimer()
      this.active = index
    },
    
    onMouseLeave () {
      this.startTimer()
    },
    
    startTimer () {
      if (this.timerId) {
        return
      }
    
      this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
        this.active = (this.active + 1) % 4
      }, 500)    
    },
    
    stopTimer () {
      clearInterval(this.timerId)
      this.timerId = null
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="item"
      :class="{ active: active === index }"
      @mouseenter="onMouseEnter(index)"
      @mouseleave="onMouseLeave"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```